# Java heap space crashing Solr query

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm not a Java guy but use Solr for searching, but after search about this issue I couldn't find out why it is happening.

I have a 30-million-records-index with no sorting and the lightest setup I could do, but I have the following exception after a few queries:

> SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.createFakeNorms(SegmentReader.java:1117)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.fakeNorms(SegmentReader.java:1125)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.norms(SegmentReader.java:1140)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexReader.norms(SolrIndexReader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight.scorer(TermQuery.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:250)
>     at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:171)  at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:988)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:884)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:341)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1317)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Then I restart tomcat and it gets back to work until a few requests for falling down again.

I'm not sorting (even I wish it) and the search os most of times by specific indexed fields (not for all of them).

Could you help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure Solr/Lucene won't die with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391758/how-to-make-sure-solr-lucene-wont-die-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: I saw that topic and read it, but the answers focus mostly in FieldCache and FieldComparator classes for sorting and that's not my case. I use Ubuntu's default configuration for starting the daemon, so, I'm trying to find out what's the best way for increasing the memory limits, term limits, etc. I did it manually and initially had no better results.

Comment: You need to provide more information so we can give you hints, at least: version of the JVM, JVM parameters (especially the memory parameters such as `-Xmx`, `-XX:*Size`, and the garbage collector parameters such as `-XX:*GC`).

Comment: ok, thanks. The running process is "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-tomcat6-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start"

Comment: as I said, that command is called by the default service installed as a package from Ubuntu's apt-get. I tried to change the deamon code ( /etc/rc3.d/*tomcat/ ) for forcing a different -Xmx and -XX but I had no effect).

Comment: I called manually with "-Xmx1200m -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10" and it lasted longer (stable until now), but not using the Ubuntu's way for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

128 MB seems low for a Solr deployment with a few millions records. You can indeed increase the maximum size of the JVM using `-Xmx`. The `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio` just changes the point at which the heap is resized, but you could also use `-Xms` with the same value as `-Xmx` to directly allocate the maximum size and avoid any resizes.

However, you may want to try and determine a more precise value for the heap instead of just throwing more memory blindly, as too much memory can be counter-productive latency-wise, because of the longer pauses during garbage collection. Using JVisualVM (even better, with the VisualGC plugin) or `jstat` on the command line, you can see how much memory Solr uses after starting, how much it uses after a request, and generally how its heap varies during your typical usage.

For example, using `jstat -gcutil <PID>`, you can see how full the young (E, as in Eden) and old (O) generations of the JVM are (the old generation is what you should be looking at, at first). Or using `jstat -gc <PID>`, you'll get the values instead of a percentage (the C columns being the capacity, i.e. the maximum, and the U columns being the actual usage). You need enough memory for Solr's working set plus what's needed to process the requests. Using that information, you can tune a bit more finely what's needed.

Comment: thanks a lot, that clarifies the logic behind the scene for a non-java dev :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have memory leak in code. You may need to take heap dump to see which objects are consuming memory.

(or)

As Brian said, you might be starting tomcat with less memory configurations. Check how much memory you have allocated for tomcat using -Xms and -Xmx commands.

Comment: Is it a leak ? Perhaps it just needs more memory than the JVM is configured for ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew: That is very valid point. Actually we should first start by checking memory configuration before deciding it is memory leak.

Comment: please take a look at my comment above :)